# Contour integrals on complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Let C be that part of the circle $z=e^{i\theta}$, where $0\le\theta\le\frac\pi2$. Evaluate $\int_{c}\frac{z}{i}dz$.

This is my first time posting my question here. I'm really poor in writing English. for that reason please understand my bad explanation. proceed to the main issue I have no idea on solving this problem and also the way how to approach the answer. There is no solution manual which means that i'm not sure what i'm solving and answer. So please i need your any advice, suggest, soulution or etc.

Comment: yours function $\frac{z}{i}$ is analytic so your integration depends only end points of integration i.e. its path independent....

Comment: @danimal, They shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z=e^{i\theta}\implies dz=ie^{i\theta}d\theta\implies {z\over i}dz=(e^{i\theta})^2d\theta\implies\int_C{z\over i}dz=\int_0^{\pi\over2}e^{2i\theta}d\theta={e^{2i\theta}\over2i}\Big{|}_{0}^{\pi\over2}=i$$

Answer (score 1):

Integration  is path independent as integrand is entire function so$$\int_{c}\frac{z}{i}dz=\int_{1}^{i}\frac{z}{i}dz=\frac{z^{2}}{2i}|_{1}^{i}
=i$$